# I dont know why the output will repeat multiple times, and I dont know how to format output.

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the last four digit from a string, and treat it as a post code.

This code will receive user input, check if the last four characters are digit.

If it is, extract it, and show it on the screen. 
If it is not, return error.

Now, I think I can extract it, but I don't know how to display it with format(I cannot simply overwrite toString() method because many other parts in my project need formatting display, while each uses different format.)

Plus, why the code generates multiple outputs, rather than one?

Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String address;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    address = scn.next();
    address=address.trim();
    String postcode = "1234";
    //this part extract postcode for further process.
    for(int count=1;count<5;count++)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(address.toCharArray()[address.length()-count]))
        {
            String[] split = postcode.split(address); 
            System.out.format("%s %s %n", "PO is: ", split);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("PO invalid!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

One possible output is this:

qweqwr2132

PO is:  [Ljava.lang.String;@a46701

PO is:  [Ljava.lang.String;@166a22b

PO is:  [Ljava.lang.String;@120cc56

PO is:  [Ljava.lang.String;@47393f

Output will display once if I have 1 digit in the end. Will display twice if I have 2 digits. Output will display up to 4 times if I have 4 or more digits in the end.

I realize there must be something wrong in **if** section, but I don't know why.

Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Your code prints up to 4 times because you have it inside of a for loop that runs up to 4 times ;).

Comment: Yes. I know this... Now I want to try a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I based my code in your idea, otherwise here is the working code:

```
public static boolean isIntegerParseInt(String str) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
    return false;
}

 public static void main(String []args){

    String postcode;
    String address;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    address = scn.next();
    address=address.trim();

    if(address.length() > 3)
    {
        String testPostCode = address.substring(address.length() - 4, address.length());
        if(isIntegerParseInt(testPostCode))
        {
            postcode = testPostCode;
            System.out.println("postcode:" + postcode);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("there is not valide address.");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for a late comment. Code works. I have learnt a lot from it. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

I took a different approach in solving your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String address;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    address = scn.next();
    address=address.trim();
    String postcode = "";

    if(address.length() < 4) {
        System.out.println("The address is less that four characters long.");

    } else {

        postcode = address.substring(address.length() - 4);

        try {
            int code = Integer.parseInt(postcode);
            System.out.println("The post code is :" + code);

        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think that if I enter `abcdefg1234` the result will be `efg1234` which will cuase the code to fail. Also, since this is HW, please do not just post code which works, try to explain what is happening, and ideally, what was wrong with the OP's approach.

Comment: In fact he postcode is located at the end part of an address, such will not extract a right postcode. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: yeah, look at this, `postcode = address.substring(address.length() - 4);`
we are taking the pass code as the last 4 characters of the address, that's what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

what about using String.substring()?

```
final int ZIPLENGTH = 4;
String input = "qweqwr2132";
String zipCode = input.substring(input.length - ZIPLENGTH); 

try {
    Integer.parseInt( zipCode );
    System.out.println("PO is: " + zipCode);
}
catch( Exception e ) {
    System.err.println("Last 4 chars are not a number");
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I want to use a sub string, but what should I say, your code is much easier to understand than my previous one, and it Does work very well! Thanks for the great work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String address;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    address = scn.next();
    address=address.trim();
    String postcode = "1234";
    //this part extract postcode for further process.
    for(int count=4;count>0;count--)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(address.toCharArray()[address.length()-count]))
        {
            System.out.format("%s %s %n", "PO is: ", address.toCharArray()[address.length()-count]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("PO invalid!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uh, now the output splits into four individual numbers, rather than a postcode. Since the for loop is not really a good idea, I am about to give up this approach.